# How do I make VBA Clear Chart dynamically and refresh with new cell range values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a chart named "VelChart". It builds a graph from a range of cell values. However, I want the chart to be cleared every time the said referenced cell values are refreshed.

This is the code that I have:

```
 Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").ChartObjects("VelChart").Activate
 ActiveChart.ChartArea.ClearContents
```

When I use the above code, it is deleting/removing the chart altogether. And when I try to reference the chart elsewhere in the code, it throws an error. How do I just clear the chart contents and not delete the chart altogether?

This is the code that I have elsewhere that I am referencing:

```
 Public Function DrawVelChart(strComponent As String)
    Select Case strComponent
        Case "Infrastructure (CI/CD/DevOps)"
            Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").ChartObjects("VelChart").Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").Range("C6:E" & iLastRow)
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Infra Velocity Trend"
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").Range("G6:G" & iLastRow)
        Case "Configuration"
            Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").ChartObjects("VelChart").Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").Range("C6:E" & iLastRow)
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Configuration Velocity Trend"
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").Range("G6:G" & iLastRow)
        Case "Analytics"
            Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").ChartObjects("VelChart").Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").Range("C6:E" & iLastRow)
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Analytics Velocity Trend"
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Velocity Tracker").Range("G6:G" & iLastRow)
    End Select
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: What error?, that code should not delete the chart object

Comment: No error, but it is not clearing out the chart. I searched quite a bit on the internet and I could not find a reason why it would not clear out the chart. Surprisingly, if I put a breakpoint and step thru the code, then it clears. What gives?

Comment: Please clarify, que question says the code deletes the chart, but the above comment says the code don't even clear the chart. Which one is it.